# Вставка пустой строки в начале каждой html страницы

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть система, разработанная с использованием `CodeIgniter`. Работает нормально, но есть сервера, на которых в начале каждой сформированной `HTML` страницы (включая и `sitemap.xml`) добавляется пустая строка, из-за чего `sitemap.xml` выдает ошибку в браузере. Не думаю чтобы это была проблема с `php` кодом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Просто догадка, в каком то файле, есть  пустая строка после закрывающего тэга "?>".

Comment: обычно эта ошибка возникает из за пустых строк после закрывающего тэга php в functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UTF-8 BOM**

При заливке на некоторые сервера через FTP автоматически меняется кодировка.

В BOM версии кодировки в начале файла есть NULL-байт. Надо проверить все файлы и переконвертировать при необходимости в обычный UTF-8.